# How do i detect firebase upload task is running or finish in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to cancel firebase upload task and which is done by

```
task.cancel();
```

But How do i detect that uploading task is finish or not, for the delete of uploaded file.
for example

```
final UploadTask task=filepath.putBytes(data);
        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });

 imageViewHolder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(task.isFinish)
                   {
                     StorageReference taskUrl= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(Linklist.get(i));
                    taskUrl.delete();
                   }
               else
                   {
                     task.cancel();
                   }
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add a listener, you can use [isComplete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask#isComplete()) to poll the UploadTask for completion.